# execute awk command with shell variables on remote server

Tags: shell-script, shell

```
start_time="2021-02-10 08:17:38"
end_time="2021-02-10 09:17:38"
ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx "awk -v start_tm=$start_time -v end_tm=$end_time '\$0 >= start_tm && \$0 <= end_tm' /var/log/app.log"
```

I am facing below error.

```
awk: cmd. line:1: 08:17:38
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error
```

The same awk command is working if I execute after SSH to the server. even I tried to keep backslash \ before & command. I am new to shell scripting, please suggest what other things need to take care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to call the [`awk` script here](/a/635113/72456), always it's good practice to have a script and call the script so you no need worry about inner variables escaping:

```
ssh user@localhost "\
    awk -v start='$start_time' -v end='$end_time' -v q=\' \
        -f /path/to/awk-script.awk /path/to/log-file"
```

also note that we used escaped *`$start_time`* and *`$end_time`* above with quotes.

---

`awk-script.awk` contains:

```
BEGIN {
        st = "date -d" q start q " +%s"
        st | getline start
        close(st)
        ed = "date -d" q end q " +%s"
        ed | getline end
        close(ed)
}
    
{
        dt = $1 " " $2
        epoch = "date -d" q dt q " +%s"
        epoch | getline dt
        close(epoch)
}

(dt >= start && dt <= end) { print }
```

Comment: can't we use `'\$0 >= start_tm && \$0 <= end_tm'` instead of script? since when I tested this is working fine. so that my command will become single line statement.

Comment: @bhr you are doing date comparison but `awk` has no "date comparison" feature. the way you are doing like that is just integer comparison like doing `awk 'BEGIN{ print (3==3x?"equal":"not-equal")}'` vs `awk 'BEGIN{ print (3=="3x"?"equal":"not-equal")}'` or `awk 'BEGIN{ print (3==3x+0?"equal":"not-equal")}'`.

Comment: ok, I understood. But for my understanding purpose what's the mistake I am doing? To make it work what's need to be change in my command ?

Comment: @bhr `ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx "awk -v start_tm='$start_time' -v end_tm='$end_time' '\$0 >= start_tm && \$0 <= end_tm' /var/log/app.log"`